# Translating SQL by Django ORM for INNER JOIN

Tags: inner-join, django-orm

There are 2 tables like below
[Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INbPx.png)

[Branch Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ls0d.png)

Branch Table has a foreign key mgr_id which relates to Employee table. The field emp_id in Employee table is related to mgr_id. Now I did a basic INNER JOIN by below SQL query and it showed correct results.

```
select blog_employee.emp_id, blog_employee.first_name, blog_branch.branch_name 
from blog_employee
join blog_branch
on blog_employee.emp_id = blog_branch.mgr_id ;
```

[SQL query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpUFL.png)

For Django ORM I tried to replicate this but cannot as I have to use branch table first as it contains the foreign key. I used the below query but it does not show correct results like SQL query above

```
myquery16 = branch.objects.select_related('mgr_id')
```

It shows a different join than INNER JOIN which is LEFT OUTER JOIN and I get 4 rows because right table becomes the employee I suppose, whereas in SQL query left table is employee.
Please help me attain or replicate the raw sql query as it works correctly but it seems I can use select_related on branch only as it has the foreign key and making branch a left table but according to sql query it is a right table.

Django query above gives all the entire columns from both tables. This is the output below showing it as LEFT OUTER JOIN when I execute "myquery16"

```
    SELECT "blog_branch"."branch_id", "blog_branch"."branch_name", "blog_branch"."mgr_id",
"blog_branch"."mgr_start_date", "blog_employee"."emp_id", "blog_employee"."first_name",
"blog_employee"."last_name", "blog_employee"."birth_day", "blog_employee"."sex",
"blog_employee"."salary", "blog_employee"."super_id", "blog_employee"."branch_id"
FROM "blog_branch" **LEFT OUTER JOIN** "blog_employee" ON ("blog_branch"."mgr_id" = "blog_employee"."emp_id")
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help] Please format code reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The LEFT OUTER JOIN can be forced to INNER JOIN.
The LEFT OUTER JOIN was giving null results also as it was not the perfect common result of say between set A and B.

Django which produced LEFT OUTER JOIN gave result set like this:
[Incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL8sO.png)

I corrected the ORM query to this below:

```
myquery16 = branch.objects.filter(mgr_id__isnull=False, mgr_start_date__isnull=False).select_related('mgr_id').annotate(emp_id=F('mgr_id__emp_id'),first_name=F('mgr_id__first_name'))
```

It worked perfect stating as INNER JOIN. Result set is: [Correct result with above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtQON.png)

If in above Django query you replace annotate by .values(), it will restrict to columns you desire.
Here is the query seen in console:

```
SELECT "blog_branch"."branch_name", "blog_branch"."mgr_id" AS "emp_id", "blog_employee"."first_name" AS "first_name" FROM "blog_branch" INNER JOIN "blog_employee" ON ("blog_branch"."mgr_id" = "blog_employee"."emp_id") WHERE ("blog_branch"."mgr_id" IS NOT NULL AND "blog_branch"."mgr_start_date" IS NOT NULL)
```

3

Below are the models for the table:

```
class branch(models.Model):
branch_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[validatePositive])
branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
mgr_id = models.ForeignKey("employee", to_field = "emp_id", db_column='mgr_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, validators=[validatePositive])
mgr_start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class employee(models.Model):
MALE = 'M'
FEMALE ='F'
SEX_CHOICES = [
    ('M', 'F'),
]
emp_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[validatePositive]) # though null not needed here
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False).............
```